# Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am getting following errors:

```
const validateOptions: ChildFormOptionProps
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Here is my ts code : getting error at `"parseInt(validateOptions.minlength)"`

```
username: (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: ValidatorFn } | null => {
            const validateOptions = PatientFormService.controlProps['username'].options;
            if (Object.keys(validateOptions).length) {
                if (control.value && control.value.length < parseInt(validateOptions.minlength)) {
                    control.setErrors({ 'incorrect': true });
                    return control.errors;
                }
            }
            return null;
        },
```

any suggestion to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `parseInt`, which accepts a `string`, with a value that has the type `number | undefined`. That's a type error, exactly what TypeScript is supposed to help you with. So what you need to do is modify the code so it doesn't try to use a `number | undefined` with `parseInt` (which makes no sense). For instance, you might add a guard for the `undefined` case, then either use the number as-is or, if you have some reason for ensuring it's an integer rather than fractional, use `Math.round`/`ceil`/`floor` as appropriate on it. For instance:

```typescript
username: (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: ValidatorFn } | null => {
    const validateOptions = PatientFormService.controlProps['username'].options;
    if (Object.keys(validateOptions).length) {
        if (control.value &&
            validateOptions.minLength !== undefined &&          // ** Guard
            control.value.length < validateOptions.minlength) { // ** No parseInt
            control.setErrors({ 'incorrect': true });
            return control.errors;
        }
    }
    return null;
},
```

...but you may have to tweak that, I had to make a couple of minor assumptions in there.